# How can i implement a view UX like notification bar closing animation?

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

If you take a look at notification bar, when closing it, the views go under each other and then finally go out of the screen. take a look at screenshots to see what i mean:

[image: no1]

[image: no2]

I want to implement a view in my application that behave just like this. 
I've looked at [these kind of tutorials](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/scrolling-techniques-for-material-design--cms-24435) that focus on `CoordinatorLayout` to implement this, but i can't find a way to implement this behaviour. Is there any other view that can help me?

Comment: Morteza Rastgoo, Try this.
https://github.com/Deepankur-Sadana/notificationAnimation